# D365FO RSAT Action ExecuteHyperlink is not supported

Tags: automated-tests, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I am using D365FO Task Recorder to document a test case where the user clicks on a hyperlink in a dropdown control to see details of a certain type of item. The downloaded XML runs in the Playback Recorder without issues but RSAT cannot Generate Test Execution and Parameters File. Here is the error message:

Cannot generate test execution files. Action ExecuteHyperlink is not supported on control ReferenceGroup. Recreate the recording without this action.

The users of my company use hyperlinks quite often so it’s impossible to record test cases avoiding this functionality.

Did anyone find or solve this hyperlink problem?

Thanks in advance, regards